# How to build jar-file with ant?

Tags: java, xml, build, ant, jvm

According to the training task, I need to create `.jar`-file with `ant`.  There are no problems with the Assembly of ordinary classes that are in `src` .

But I have in project present `logger`, `libraries` to him and `.properties` file.

because of this, errors fly out:

```
[javac] error: package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist
```

and

```
error: cannot find symbol
[javac] error: private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Hello.class);
```

I have `build.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Runner" default="run">
    <!-- define names of directories -->
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="classes" location="${build}/classes"/>
    <!-- define all targets -->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includeAntRuntime="false"/>
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classname="${ant.project.name}" classpath="${classes}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="package" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${build}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main–Class" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

and this stracture

[image]

**How and where to gather library and property in Java file to jar-file was executable?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

> ```
> <path id="classpath">
>     <fileset dir="${lib}">
>         <include name="**/*.jar"/>
>     </fileset>
> </path>
>
> <target name="init" depends="clean" description="starts">
>     <tstamp/>
> </target>
>
> <target name="clean" depends="package-to-jar" description="clean up">
>     <delete dir="${classes}"/>
>     <delete file="${external-lib}"/>
> </target>
>
> <target name="package-to-jar" depends="package-external-lib" description="packing all project into a jar-file">
>     <jar destfile="${jar}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes}">
>         <manifest>
>             <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
>         </manifest>
>         <zipfileset src="${external-lib}"/>
>     </jar>
>     <delete dir="${classes}"/>
>     <delete file="${external-lib}"/>
> </target>
>
> <target name="package-external-lib" depends="compile" description="packing external libraries into a jar-file">
>     <jar destfile="${external-lib}">
>         <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib}">
>             <include name="**/*.jar"/>
>         </zipgroupfileset>
>     </jar>
> </target>
>
> <target name="compile" description="compile the source">
>     <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
>     <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" classpathref="classpath"/>
>     <copy todir="${classes}">
>         <fileset dir="${src}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
>     </copy>
> </target>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need include required library folders to class path

```
<path id="class.path">
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
</path>
```

and add reference to javac task in compile target

```
<target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
           <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" includeAntRuntime="false">
        <classpath refid="class.path" />
      </javac>
</target>
```

aftewards include all properties file to jar

```
<target name="package" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${build}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes}">
        <include name="*.properties"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main–Class" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
</target>
```